# PowerShell Sorting CSV Output values in Get-MailboxFolderStatistics cmdlet Office 365

Tags: powershell, office365

I have created a PowerShell script based on aggregated research from Microsoft docs and articles online. The purpose of the script is to export mailbox folder statistics in office 365. I have two problems.

1 How to sort the exported values in csv as per script order in New Object, currently, the values shuffle each time I run the script?

2 The recoverableitem column in the csv output, it returns ```System.Object[]`` the expected output should be numeric, correct me if I got it wrong.

Below is the script.

```
$All = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
$All | ForEach-Object {
    
    $mailbox = $_.DisplayName
    $inboxstats = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $mailbox -FolderScope Inbox
    $deleteditem = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -identity $mailbox -FolderScope DeletedItems
    $sentitem = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -identity $mailbox -FolderScope SentItems
    $recoverableitem = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -identity $mailbox -FolderScope RecoverableItems

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
   
        UserPrincipalName = $mailbox
        InboxItems = $inboxstats.ItemsInFolderAndSubfolders
        DeletedItems = $deleteditem.ItemsInFolderAndSubfolders
        SentItems = $sentitem.ItemsInFolderAndSubfolders
        RecoverableItems = $recoverableitem.ItemsInFolderAndSubfolders
        InboxSize = $inboxstats.FolderandSubFolderSize
      
    }

} | Export-CSV "C:\resultsv12.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Currently, i'm unable to attach a file or snapshot because am new, and do not have 10 reputations. The issue description is clear.

Comment: Pipe to `Sort-Object -Property`. Try `Out-String` for the recoverable property as well.

Comment: RecoverableItems is an array, do want to list the items or a count of them?

Comment: For recoverableitems, i need to count.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala i will appreciate if you can add a snippet of how it will look in the script. I tried adding `| Sort-Object -property` at the beginning of the new object values but the scripts shows its incomplete.

Comment: I figured out the fix, for sorting objects, i added the `| sort-object` after the last closing curly brace of the script, and i listed the column names, and recoverable items, i added `.count` at the end of its variable value. Thank you team for assistance.